# Min, Max, Group By and DateDiff

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to optimise many MySQL statements into one but have come across a problem.

MySQL query:

```
  SELECT companyid, COUNT(*) AS total 
    FROM timesheet 
   WHERE userId='1' 
     AND DATEDIFF(MIN(startDate), MAX(endDate)) <= 77 
GROUP BY companyid 
  HAVING total = 11
```

What I'm trying to do is select all companies where exactly 11 records exist and the first and last records were created within 11 weeks of each other. The error I get is "Invalid use of group function".

This is to do with the `MIN(), MAX()` and `DATEDIFF()` part but I can't for the life of me figure it out!

Comment: You have circular logic in your query. :)

Answer (score 2):

Aggregate functions needs to be in the HAVING clause, not the WHERE clause.  (eg your `DATEDIFF(MIN(startDate), MAX(endDate)) <= 77` condition)

Think of HAVING as applying to grouped records, and WHERE applying to individual records before being grouped.